# Crystal Reports Details of Details

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to build a Crystal Report for a picking slip.  My data structure is as follows: Each pick slip document has one header (of course), which contains any number of lines.  Each line represents an inventory item that needs to be picked.  However, each line has any number of BinLines linked to it, which contains information about the qty of the inventory item to be picked from a given bin.  So the inventory line may have a total qty to pick equal to 15.  But that qty could be split such that 5 must come from bin X and 4 from bin Y and 6 from bin Z.  So the links in the report data are setup such that BinLine is a child of Line and Line is a child of Header.  Now I understand that I would define my Crystal Report so that the Page Header section contains the header fields, and I would define the Details section to contain fields related to the inventory item.  But I don't understand how to model the BinLines...is this where I would add a second Detail section to the report, such I have (Details a) containing the Line fields, and (Details b) containing the BinLines fields?

EDIT
Sorry I should have mentioned that my data source is an xml file (based on a defined XSD), so it's not like the InventoryLine is being repeated for every occurrence of an associated BinLine (like it would have had my data source been a database view or stored proc).  Hence I don't see Groupings working for this.

Comment: Why don't you draw up the hierarchy of the data? That will make it easy to understand.

Comment: @ShawndeWet: You haven't told us how you want the data to appear on the report.

Comment: Hi Mark,  I'd like the data to appear as Kangkan has laid it out in his answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to draw up the structure of the data. I know, it is not complete.

```
Pink Slip Document
  |
  |-Inventory Item 1
  |    |
  |    |-BinLines 1
  |    |
  |    |-BinLines 2
  |-Inventory Item 2
  |
  |-Inventory Item 3
```

But, if it is something similar to it, you can have it with multiple groups in the report.

For specific things, you can look at using sub-reports.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that my data source is an xml file (based on a defined XSD), so it's not like the InventoryLine is being repeated for every occurrence of an associated BinLine.  Hence I don't see Groupings working for this. (The hierarchy you have drawn up is exactly right though.)

Comment: So how are you retrieving data for each "Inventory Item" etc? Cannot you show some details of the XML or the XSD? You need not have the data in this structure, but it should be retrievable in such a structure.

Comment: There's basically a Web Service call that returns xml data in the hierarchical structure you depicted above.  This xml data conforms to an XSD on which I am basing the Crystal Report.